# The different meanings of "life"? 生気／生活／ライフ／生命／一生／人生／命

Tags: word-choice, words, definitions

I was looking through a dictionary and came across 生活. My original question was

> Is this the difference between 生気／生活?
>
> 生気 would be like an idea of life. more abstract
>
> 生活 would be concrete. So like something/one's life.

My new question is can you help me to understand the different ways "life" is said in Japanese? I actually forgot about 人生 and 命 when I wrote the question. I didn't know about ライフ／生命／一生 (and others?). I think 人生 would usually be when talking about a person's life right?

Comment: There are many more words that translate to life: 命{いのち}, 人生, ライフ, 生命, 一生, … If you're just trying to say "life", you have to be more precise and maybe give us a couple of example sentences. If you're really only interested in the difference between 生気 and 生活, then example sentences would still be very helpful.

Comment: Yes, what Earthliŋ said.  Context is key.

Comment: Truth is 生活 and 生気 mean very different things from each other regardless of the context.

Comment: Sorry, I do not have sentences. I was looking through a dictionary, but it is very basic. Does not give example sentences so I can understand better. I have updated my question!

Comment: Even this list of words for life is still incomplete. I'd suggest finding a way to narrow it down if possible..

Comment: There's also 生涯

Answer (score 16, accepted):

生活【せいかつ】 is English *life*, *livelihood*, or *living*; day-to-day activities of people.

命【いのち】 is *life*; it's something we lose when we die. Synonyms: 生【せい】、生命【せいめい】

生気【せいき】 is more like *liveliness*, *spirit*, or *energy*. Synonyms: 元気【げんき】、活力【かつりょく】

一生【いっしょう】 is a *whole life* of someone. Synonym: 生涯【しょうがい】

人生【じんせい】 is *human's (whole) life*; use this only for humans, of course.

ライフ is rarely used unless you're a video gamer. When used, it's the same as 生活 or 命.

Examples:

- 生活が苦しい difficult to live on (due to financial problems)
- 生活保護 public assistance
- 快適な生活 comfortable life
- 交通事故で命を失う lose one's life in a traffic accident
- 残り少ない命 little time left to live
- 命が惜しければ... if you value your life...
- 生気のない顔 colorless face
- 声から生気が消える speak in an inanimate voice
- 生気が戻る become energetic again
- 一生で一度だけ／人生で一度だけ once in a lifetime
- 一生の仕事 one's lifework
- ライフが少ない health is low (in games)

Comment: You sir are a braver soul than most for answering such an open-ended question.

Comment: Oh, yes, that reminded me of 魂【たましい】, which means *soul* or *spirit*, something that doesn't vanish when we die. It's often used metaphorically as is the case with English. (侍魂【さむらいだましい】 = samurai spirit)

Comment: And of course, the counter for 'lives' in a video game sense is [機]{き}.