# What is a word for "participation" that resembles "kameseru"?

Tags: words

According to the article ["On Being Late to Work in Japan | 遅出"](http://thisjapaneselife.org/2011/03/09/japan-work-ethic/) (linked from [this post](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/28274/10298) at The Workplace):

> The word for participation – *kameseru* – has a special significance which also explains why Japanese bureaucracy is so overwhelming...

As far as I know, カメセル is not a Japanese word, and it doesn't look like any variations on the vowels (カーメセル or カメーセル or カメセール or カメセルー or some combination thereof) or gemination (カメッセル) give you anything useful either. Nor can I think of any near-homophones (コメセル? カメスル?) that mean anything related to "participation".

What word might the article have meant?

Comment: That is not the only confused Japanese in that article. What is 外面九天??? 遅出 exists as a word, but doesn't carry the nuance of being later than you're supposed to. 遅刻 is probably the word he's looking for.

Comment: @dainichi I was thinking that maybe 外面九天 was a pun or an inside joke of some variety? (Admittedly, that is a generous interpretation. According to the author's [about me page](http://thisjapaneselife.org/about/), he worked in Japan for three years on JET, but I suppose it's possible that he somehow got through that without learning a lick of the language.)

Comment: Good answers to this question interest me greatly because I explain to my students on the first day that I grade on 参加 not 出席. And more ways to express that are great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the author of that post, the 'insufferable self-absorbed hipster.'

It was a typo - I'd meant 'kamei-suru' but was pretty bad at Japanese when I first arrived (and still am not very good, but continue to learn and practice even after having left the country). It's this:

加盟 + する

And basically refers to 'becoming a part of the group' by engaging and participating in the group's activities. I think in hindsight it may have a much more limited function.

Comment: Oh!  In that case, would you be willing to share how you came up with `生命を外面九天です`?

Comment: That is not even what 加盟する means.

Comment: Please see naruto's comment on Earthling's answer for why 加盟する isn't used how you think it is.

Comment: "生命を外面九天です" was written for me by a friend in Japan. It means "Life Outside the Palace," or at least I thought it did. How would you say it better? Again, that was written by a native.

Also, why is there so much hostility toward me in this forum? I've never claimed to be an expert in the language.

Comment: How about 参加する for "to participate" (or 参加 for "participation")?

Comment: (九天 is "Nine days" in Chinese...)

Comment: "Life outside the palace"... Literally [宮殿]{きゅうでん}(or[王宮]{おうきゅう}/[宮廷]{きゅうてい})の[外]{そと}での[暮]{く}らし ... maybe 宮殿(or)を[離]{はな}れて暮らす? / 宮殿を離れた暮らし? or 宮殿を出て暮らす??

Comment: (Maaaybe [九天]{きゅうてん} was a typo for [宮殿]{きゅうでん}??)

Comment: @Choko: I think you hit the nail on the head, even though 生命を外面宮殿です is still malformed...

Comment: As for 生命, please read [this article](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/16293/). 外面 is more like "exterior" or "appearance" than "outside of ～". A palace is 宮殿, not 九天. And is this *palace* a metaphor for your home(land) or something? Never heard such metaphor at least in Japanese.

Comment: Yes it was a metaphor, life outside the palace is a reference to Siddhartha (the Herman Hesse novel) when the title character leaves home and encounters all the things that lead him to understand the world more completely outside of his own bubble.

Answer (score 7):

I think it might refer to [加盟]{かめい}する, although in the context of leaving early or not from work, 参加する would have been a much better fit.

Still, my guess is the author just asked someone "How do you say *participation* in Japanese?" and someone came up with 加盟する.

Comment: Usually 加盟する refers to a company or a country joining a larger group/association, as in "SONYはBlu-ray Disc Associationに加盟しています" "フランスはEUの加盟国です". A person participating in day-to-day work is not 加盟する. (I'm not saying my answer is better; mine is also awkward)

Comment: I wrote in my answer that 加盟する is definitely not participation in the sense used in the article. (I hope that's not what triggered the downvote.) I still think that someone who obviously has no clue about Japanese is much more likely to come up with a(n incorrect) kanji compound in dictionary form than with an unusual interpretation of 噛む in a rather advanced conjugation of the word. Anyway, what the writer really referred to is anyone's guess...

Comment: 「加盟する」って書いてあるような気が。。。私、皆さんと違うページ見てます？　http://i.stack.imgur.com/oUxBa.png

Comment: @Choko -- Looks like the article author [realized it was a typo](http://thisjapaneselife.org/2011/03/09/japan-work-ethic/#comment-8391) and fixed the article accordingly.  So it **used** to say "*kameseru*", but **now** it correctly says "*kamei suru*".  :)

Comment: I think my answer doesn't deserve a downvote, considering that my guess turned out to be correct.

Comment: 参りました(^^;)　まさか正解が判明するとは…

Answer (score 2):

The closest word to *kameseru* which means "participation" is, maybe 噛【か】ませる?

[噛む](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/45040/m0u/) sometimes means "get (partially) involved", often (but not necessarily) referring to bad/illegal things. My boss may say something like this:

> やれる仕事はないかもしれないけどさ、とりあえずA君もこのプロジェクトに噛ませといてよ。
>   Though I doubt he has something to do, let A join this project for now, too.

Well, this expression is natural, but uncommon. The general idea of "everyone's (full) participation" is usually not described by this word. I may be missing something.

Answer (score 2):

It appears as if we might be dealing with a garbled 任【まか】せる, 'to entrust'.

Basically, the word *kameseru* is only found in two contexts: The article in question and excerpts plagiarized from it; and questions asking what the word *kameseru* means such as a similar discussion on [reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/japan/comments/24wwqf/what_is_kameseru/).

Answer (score 0):

The most common Japanese word for “participation” will be 参加（さんか）する、like パーティ（組合、会議、ゲーム）に参加する- participate / join in a party (union, meeting, game).

加盟(かめい）is a big word to mean “joining,” that’s applied to big entities e.g. organizations and countries, like EU（三国間協定、連合）に加盟する- participate in Europe Union (three-country treaty, National Labor Union League).

The word, 加盟 that reads “kamei” have nothing to do with a late-coming to work.

There is no word that reads and being vocalized as “kameseru” in Japanese language.