# What word that resembles "teikkai" might refer to "the provenance of a food"?

Tags: words, food

The introduction to the 10th Anniversary Edition of [*Vegetarian Cooking for Everyone*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0767927478) contains the following passage on page 4 (emphasis added):

> Vegetarians have often used the phrase "I don't eat anything with a face on it," to describe their food choices as plant-based. But there is another interpretation of that phrase "food with a face." **The Japanese have a word for it, *teikkai*, which refers to the provenance of a food―where it comes from, how it was raised, who grew it.** It is the opposite of "general foods," those faceless foods that come to us anonymously from a vague source: foods without soul.

Never having heard of *teikkai*, I [tried to look it up in a dictionary](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/srch/jn/%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%81%A3%E3%81%8B%E3%81%84/m0u/) - and of course, I found nothing. [Searching for `"teikkai"` in Latin script](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22teikkai%22) gives only [one relevant result](http://inspiritual.biz/the-zenful-kitchen/2011/6/16/teikkai.html), which is by some other reader of the same book and provides no further insight. My best guess would be that the author meant *tekkai* or *teikai*, but then again, none of 撤回・鉄拐 nor 低回・停会 mean anything remotely related.

Is there a word that resembles *teikkai* in Japanese that has something to do with "the provenance of a food"?

(Structurally-similar question from some time back: [What is a word for "participation" that resembles "kameseru"?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/17723/))

Comment: 「[提携]{ていけい}」とかですかね・・・???　「産消提携」とかの・・・

Comment: Would contacting the original author http://deborahmadison.com be a good solution? It's apparently beyond my poor Japanese vocabulary...

Comment: Contacting the author is probably the best idea.  I'm not sure whether or not this question can be answered without doing so.

Answer (score 2):

I believe chocolate-san is right and I have the website of the Japan Organic Agriculture Association in [Japanese](http://www.joaa.net/mokuhyou/teikei.html) and [English](http://www.joaa.net/english/teikei.htm#ch5-1) to prove it.

It turns out this "teikei" 「提携」 (lit. "cooperation") has been around since 1978. The longer names are 産消提携{さんしょうていけい} and 生消提携{せいしょうていけい}.

It seems the problem, aside from getting the transliteration wrong, was that the author thought it was a common word. Or more precisely, that the definition she gave was the main meaning of the word. In actuality, the JOAA started a movement and named it teikei. (See section 3 of the English website).