# What is the Japanese word (noun) that means “the bittersweetness of a brief, fading moment of transcendent beauty.”?

Tags: words, word-requests

The article written by Emily Anthes, appearing in the New Yorker, May 12 issue under the title, “The Glossary of Happiness” wraps up with the following paragraph:

> Lomas (a lecturer in applied positive psychology at the University of East London) returned to the University of East London and launched the
>   Positive Lexicography Project, an online glossary of untranslatable
>   words. “If you just put them out there and people are aware of them,
>   then—almost like linguistic natural selection—people will find ones
>   that appeal to them, and they might start using them,” Lomas said. If
>   he succeeds, we may stroll through these waning days of spring more
>   aware of aware—**the Japanese noun for “the bittersweetness of a brief,
>   fading moment of transcendent beauty**.”

I can’t think up a Japanese word (noun) equivalent to the notion, “the bittersweetness of a brief, fading moment of transcendent beauty” in English.
Would you suggest me any Japanese counterpart that comes up to your mind?

Comment: Did you realize that the article mentioned the (romanized) Japanese word (*aware*)?

Comment: Seems like 侘び寂び (わびさび) at least needs a mention here.

Comment: @Earthing. Gosh! Jumped the gun.  I took 'aware' for an English word, 'aware' of awareness, and thought the structure of 'days of spring more aware of aware' is strange. The answer was given int the text.
A sour grape for my misreading 哀れ. 'aware' is that 'aware' here  in "waning days of spring more aware of aware' is apparently functions as an adjective, but the author is calling it a noun.

Comment: Cont'd. 哀れ on its alone doesn't describe the sense of "the bittersweetness of a brief, fading moment of transcendent beauty.” The author should have added to ものの to 哀れ.

Comment: @YoichiOishi I see. This reminds me of this question: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/17723/1628

Comment: @Earthing. Interesting. I added my answer to the above question about 'kameire'.

Comment: Cont'd By the way, we don't feel ものの哀れ in spring, as quoted by the OP, when flowers bloom,  tree's foliage is green, and everything starts fresh. ものの哀れ is usually referred to the melancholic feeling in autumn. Don't you think so?

Answer (score 10):

The word the writer meant was 哀れ

> If he succeeds, we may stroll through these waning days of spring more aware of *aware*

In English, foreign words are often typeset in italics, and this article follows the convention (although your copypaste did not copy the italics over.)

Comment: Does 哀れ really have such a specific meaning? o,o

Comment: @kuchitsu I don't think so. Foreign words tend to be presented as mystical and bizarre concepts by a certain kind of English speaker.

Comment: Googled a bit, maybe they meant  [物の哀れ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono_no_aware).

Comment: 哀れ in modern Japanese normally means *pitiful*, *miserable*, etc., but in archaic Japanese, [哀れ had positive meanings](http://kobun.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%82%E3%81%AF%E3%82%8C%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8A) like *impressive*, *heart-touching*, *lovely*, etc. もののあはれ is a word used today to refer to the archaic definition of 哀れ/あはれ.